# MS Exchange - log of basic email responces - bounce, spam, etc?

Tags: exchange, logging

Morning all,

Before we move our transactional email to a full "Marketing ESP", I'd like to review basic delivery stat's from our current Exchange server.

I believe read / open receipts have to be manually turned on (which I doubt the have been), but I would expect Exchange to recieve, and store, receipts from the target mail server - i.e bounce / undeliverable, and presumably active spam reports.

I know the recipient mail server will (usually) send a "undeliverable" responce email, but there will be literally thousands of these - assuming they havent just been deleted.

Is there some "log" that would show these?

Basically, I'm trying to work out a basic KPI flow, some or all of the following:

Sent
Delivered
Opened
Spam

(NB - I know some of those are not available by default - but surely some are?).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to track the NDR message generated from your server? You can use the command `get-messagetrackinglog -recipients "UserA@contoso.com" -EventID "FAIL" -Start "7/1/2019 3:59:00 PM" -End "9/8/2019 4:09:00 PM"`, referring to this [similar case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/01a85053-f474-458a-86f2-e9c2ee9eedfb/message-tracking-details-for-bounced-back-emails?forum=exchangesvr3rdpartyapps).

You can also configure a postmaster address in the organization if you want to be able to monitor NDRs. Detailed steps are listed [here](https://msundis.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/configure-postmaster-microsoft-exchange-recipient-and-ndr-forwarding-in-exchange-server-2007-and-2010/), you can have a look.

Comment: Hi, has the issue been fixed now?

Comment: Please let me know if the suggestions are helpful.